# How can align each line of a textarea element, to left or right based on first character in that line?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Lets say I have a textarea and I want to make it so if the user input was a `ltr` language or numbers only that line turns `ltr`. so if the user input was `rtl` language it should turn that single line `rtl`. just like telegram web version.
and whats important is I want the text to be saved with this alignments so I can show them in the browser as it is.
like this image:[image]

**EDIT:**

I actually want something like telegram desktop text input that aligns the lines without change all the other lines based on first character of the line. But I want it to be on a web page so HTML/CSS/JQUERY/JAVASCRIPT and so on. I don't know nodeJs so I prefer not to use that.

IS THIS EVEN POSSIBLE?

Comment: add your tried code...?

Comment: what if user write something like this `صارف کا نام is Bruce wayne`?

Comment: in that case if the first character of the line was english it should be ltr. otherwise rtl.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are suppose to use **regex** to check whether textbox contains English text or not. Check below snippet for reference. If it doesn't has english text use `dir="rtl"` to align right.

```js
var english = /^[A-Za-z0-9 ]*$/;
$('.myInput').each(function() {
  if (!english.test($(this).val())) {
    $(this).attr('dir', 'rtl');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="myInput" value="صارف کا نام">
<input type="text" class="myInput" value="Some Text">
```

Comment: yes. but `dir` attribute make whole `textarea` text `rtl` or `ltr`. I want to to this for each line. so if the first line was english text, it should be `ltr` and if the second line was arabic or other `rtl` languages only the second line should be rtl. not all other lines.

Comment: @mohammadfallah.rasoulnejad as per my understanding what you are asking is not possible as because we cannot style each lines of textarea as it is a input field, not displaying one.

Comment: so, isnt there any options to format text and add some ltr or rtl with some span tags in the text? so in this case the text area show it normally but save it and that span and ltr make its format in the browser?

Comment: do you mean to put html span tag inside textarea and it should show only text without tags?

Comment: then you are suppose to use html editors instead of textarea